# WPF Custom Control in separate namesapce

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to make Visual C# app, which is using UserControl (WPF).
By default, VS Community 2015 C# generates UserControl in the same namespace as main program. It's built correctly.
I'd like to separate it in it's own namespace for possible future reuse.
I change auto-generated code to have UserControl in separate namespace.

Here is my code

UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="nsTabI2CMemRW.TabI2CMemRW"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:nsTabI2CMemRW"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="AddrH"/>
        <Label x:Name="AddrH_Label"/>
    </Grid>
```

C# class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using WpfApplication1;    // This is my main app namespace

namespace nsTabI2CMemRW
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TabI2CMemRW.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TabI2CMemRW : UserControl
    {
        public TabI2CMemRW()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            ((WpfApplication1.MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).InitializeComponent();  //InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Main Windows XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:UserControl="clr-namespace:nsTabI2CMemRW"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="649.005" Width="620.667" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Margin="0,0,0.4,0.2">
        <TabControl.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup/>
        </TabControl.BindingGroup>
        <TabItem x:Name="I2CMemReadWrite" Header="I2C Mem Read/Write">

            <UserControl:TabI2CMemRW Margin="0,0,-0.2,278.2"/>

        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" Width="75"/>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Designer shows error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" for line

```
<UserControl:TabI2CMemRW Margin="0,0,-0.2,278.2"/>
```

Program compiled fine but first tab (where my UserControl should be) is blank.

Comment: Changing autogenerated code by hand is usually not a good idea

Comment: you call the `InitializeComponent` of the `MainWindow` inside the UserControl. This can not work and is more than wrong. And I guess that `Application.Current.MainWindow` is null because you are in the middle of initializing the MainWindow -> it can not exist while you creating it. This is why you end up with a NullRefernence Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this `((WpfApplication1.MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).InitializeComponent();` was wrong! Error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" relates to this code (Found using VS debugger as in this post [WPF, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' in Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533539/wpf-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-designer). I think it's useful for similar cases with WPF).

After commenting-out line (see above) and leaving only `InitializeComponent()` and recompiling code twice - it works!
Also I've checked that right code-behind file bound to XAML file ([Accidentally deleted the code behind for an Xaml file. How do I add the code behind again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023496/accidentally-deleted-the-code-behind-for-an-xaml-file-how-do-i-add-the-code-beh)).

And also this lines are important `xmlns:UserControl="clr-namespace:nsTabI2CMemRW"`
 and `<UserControl:TabI2CMemRW Margin="0,0,-0.2,278.2"/>`. I think I can missed them first time. (After `xmlns:` can be any name, not only UserControl)

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong here, cant answer them all. try comenting
 ((WpfApplication1.MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).InitializeComponent();

and leaving

InitializeComponent();

instead in your C# class

Comment: Yes, this `((WpfApplication1.MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).InitializeComponent();` was wrong! Error "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" relates to this code.